# arping not working when called from a script

Tags: unix, duplicates

I am using an `arping` command to find duplicate IP's on the network, before assigning it to my device. I use this command

`arping -D -I ${NET_DEVICE} -c 10 ${IPADDR}`

After that, I check with `$?` for the response and decides, if it's duplicated or not.

The problem is, this command returns as `not duplicated` when I call it from my `network_reset` script. When I call it individually from outside, it works perfectly.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Which arping is this? There's at least two.

Comment: @Thomas > sorry. I am a beginner. I am not aware of more than one. I followed this following man page https://linux.die.net/man/8/arping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had similar issues with programs that do work in signal handlers. I got different behaviour on the command line compared to when run within a script.

I see that `iputils-arping`, which you're probably using, seems to violate POSIX in the same way that I've seen. See [signal(7)](https://linux.die.net/man/7/signal) for a list of functions allowed. `iputils-arping` uses many more.

This may be the cause of what you see.

You could try the [portable arping](http://www.habets.pp.se/synscan/programs.php?prog=arping).